# Microphone issue in audio streaming using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, windows-xp, audio-streaming

I executed the command

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

to find out that the audio device is 'Realtek HD Audio Input'.

[image]

But executing the command

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek HD Audio Input" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -re -f rtp://10:14:35:12:1234
```

gives the error
"Could not find audio device. audio='Microphone (Realtek HD Audio Input: Input/output error"

[image]

I have checked for the working of the microphone and it works fine. Please let me know what is the issue here.

The machine runs on Windows-XP SP2.

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i audio="Microphone (Realtek HD Audio Input"` list correct information about the microphone

Comment: No! it gives an error "Could not find audio device". But the command - 'ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy' shows Realtek HD Audio Input as the audio device.

Comment: Not 100% sure but is the "Microphone (" prefix really needed?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: yes you are right! it was not really needed! thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Ok, i formulated that as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the input and screenshots given, it seems that you are using the wrong name (apparently could be from an example in another post), if the device is named `Realtek HD Audio Input` then that is what should be passed to the command line call to `ffmpeg`.